# Is it possible to mark a Tree node and path to it?

Tags: trees

I have the Tree :
[image]

```
TreeForm[Criminals["cat" , "dog", "human"["killer", "thug", "macho"]],
  DirectedEdges -> True,
  VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[
      Panel@Rotate[#2, -\[Pi]/2], #1] &)] // Rotate[#, \[Pi]/2] &
```

Is it possible to mark node macho with a bold frame and mark the path from root to it (example bigger line) ?

Another issue is how do I fix so that when I exported the graph looks like this :
(I used paint print screen :( )
[image]

Comment: Take a look at `TreeGraph[]` on the docs. It offers much more flexibility

Comment: No it doesn't. I can have nodes with same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myVertexes = {"Criminals", "cat", "dog", "human", "killer", "thug", "macho"};

myVertexLabels = 
  Table[myVertexes[[i]] -> 
    Placed[Rotate[
      Panel[myVertexes[[i]], 
       Background -> 
        If[AnyTrue[{"Criminals", "human", "macho"}, 
           # == myVertexes[[i]] &], Orange, Yellow]], -\[Pi]/2], Center], 
           {i, Length[myVertexes]}];

myEdgeShape[el_, ___] := Arrow[el, 0.2];

CriminalTree = 
  TreeGraph[{"Criminals" -> "cat", "Criminals" -> "dog", 
    Style["Criminals" -> "human", Thick, Orange], "human" -> "killer",
     "human" -> "thug", Style["human" -> "macho", Thick, Orange]},
   DirectedEdges -> True,
   EdgeShapeFunction -> myEdgeShape,
   VertexLabels -> myVertexLabels];

Rotate[Image[CriminalTree], \[Pi]/2]
```

---

[image]

And here is a direct screen shot of this figure inserted into a Pages document, showing it is in proper orientation.

[image]

And here is a direct screen shot of this figure inserted into an MS Word document, showing it in proper orientation.

[image]

And here is a direct screen shot of this figure inserted into an Adobe Illustrator document, showing it in proper orientation

[image]

And here is a direct screen shot of this figure inserted in MS Powerpoint document, showing it in proper orientation.

[image]

Comment: try adding a tab at the beginning of your code to typeset; FYI it does not work in its current form.

Comment: The code is giving an error:
The specified setting for the option PanelBoxOptions, Background cannot be used.

Comment: The option works fine in v. 10.0.0.

Comment: The Vertex must be also rotated :(

Comment: Now it looks fine but when I copy image and paste it in Paintbrush in windows still looks nor right :(

Comment: I copy as pdf and bitmap and paste into Adobe products, Preview on the Mac and all my imaging programs without problems.  (I use neither Paintbrush nor Windows.)  Try copying or Exporting it as a pdf or bitmap or other format.  At the very worst (and you shouldn't have to do this) take a screen shot of the graph.

Comment: Well I must resume to the stupid print screen method because in Windows 8 the image is screwed .... Anyway I wonder why the tree graphics quality is so low and pixelated?