# Using different colors in TreeForm?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

I've used `TreeForm`, and I appreciate that the syntax is fairly short, especially in comparison with `TreeGraph`.

Is it possible specify a different colors in `TreePlot` for coloring a section of the nodes and the paths to those nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
framedWithColor[color_] := Function[{position, label},
  {Text[Framed[label, Background -> color], position]}
];

TreeForm[
  {{1, 2}, {3, 4}},
  VertexRenderingFunction -> framedWithColor[Pink]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Anyway, Treegraph offers a lot of flexibility:

```
nodes = {RandomInteger[#] , # + 1} & /@ Range[0, 30];
rn = Range@Length@nodes;
crules = Rule @@@ Partition[Riffle[rn, ColorData[15, "ColorList"]], 2];
g = TreeGraph[UndirectedEdge @@@ nodes, VertexSize -> 0.4,  VertexStyle -> crules];
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph@FindShortestPath[g, 1, 30], GraphHighlightStyle -> "Dashed"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Terse code is nice, flexibility is wonderful.

Comment: it has one major drawback that u cannot have children of a node who is children of another node

Comment: i put a link in my original comment

Comment: `TreeGraph[]` supports all possible operations on Graphs-

Comment: @timoftebogdan `TreeGraph[]` is much more flexible than `TreePlot[]` and `TreeForm[]` for this kind of things. I told you before, but you don't like it :). [See my comment under your previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66495/193)

Comment: I already told you that i need as children to a node a node that is children to another node , aka duplicates. This is not possible with TreeGraph and i find Mathematica package useless to be honest because this simple feature missing...dissapointed

Comment: @timoftebogdan Oh, I see. You're confounding the Vertex name with the Vertex Label !

Comment: `TreePlot` seems to accept anything as a node (number, string, etc.), whereas `TreeGraph` seems to require a number.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal nodes of TreeForm are apparently all wrapped in an insidious HoldForm such that one cannot easily give them separate colors.

That is:

```
ii = 0; 
TreeForm[Nest[{#, ++ii} &, ii, 3],
  VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Black, 
     Text[#2, #1, 
      Background -> (Hue[
         Switch[#2, 0, 0.1, HoldForm@1, 0.2, 2, 0.3, 3, 0.4, List, 
          0.8, _, 0]])]} &)]
```

[image: treeform bug]